# the type or namespace name 'runtime' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio-2013, assembly-references

I'm writing a deployment application to programmatically deploy site collections and apply templates and master pages. When I try to build the application I get a bunch of errors about a missing assembly reference (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime)

I added the missing reference and the errors disappeared to be replaced by a single new error:

> 2  The type or namespace name 'Runtime' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference)

No I'm not missing an assembly reference, I just added it to fix the other errors and the intellisense wavy red line for this error is in the 'Using' statement itself. Its like VS2013 believes the .dll doesn't exist despite it being added to the projects reference list.

I'm completely stuck and google is no help, can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you also need to add a reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`.
That is a separate assembly, that needs to be referenced on top of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`

Comment: I have added it. That is the assembly that is causing the error.

Comment: The error message do point at the fact that you have not added it as an actual reference in your project. Can you post a screenshot of the "References" folder in your projekt when you have highlighted the `Runtime`dll? Also, check for version mismatch between the two dll:s

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comments on my original quesion, here is a screenshot of the assembly reference in the references folder. I can only find one version of this assembly so I don't think its a version mismatch.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you to update your question with these details, rather than post it as an answer.